# How to see execution path line by line in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

When we run a java code,how to view a flow of execution of the code by highlighting the syntax time to time until meet the termination point.

Comment: Do you mean, how to use the debugger?

Comment: I cannot understand really what is going-on at debugger and why is it taking long time. And cannot we see a short time demo for execution order?

Answer (score 1):

**Stepping through the execution of a Java program**

When a thread is suspended, the step controls can be used to step through the execution of the program line-by-line. If a breakpoint is encountered while performing a step operation,  the execution will suspend at the breakpoint and the step operation is ended.

Here : [NetBeans IDE Document](https://netbeans.org/features/java/debugger.html)

Comment: I just like to view the execution order/navigation code set. I am not meant the bug finding. It is just sawing there is not bug and it is finished. I wish to see the highlighting of execution in order for getting programming logic understood.